# how to pass first column value column value has filter in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my below data frame "df" sorted by date

```
item  price    date
  A    11.2   2021-12-31
  B    32.4   2021-12-31
  C    75.5   2021-12-31 
  A    89.3   2021-12-30
  B    12.2   2021-12-30 
  C    14.2   2021-12-30
```

basically I just need the Data at the last available date

i.e

```
 item  price    date
  A    11.2   2021-12-31
  B    32.4   2021-12-31
  C    75.5   2021-12-31
```

I tried the same with the below code , its not work as expected. I am new to pandas kindly help.

```
df = df.set_index(['date'])
df = df.loc[df['date'][0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the indices of the maximum dates for each item, and then select them:

```
idxs = df.groupby(['item'])['date'].transform(max) == df['date']
print(df[idxs])
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can always use `dict =  df.to_dict()` or `list = df.toList()` and use a dict or a list that you are probably more experienced with.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your dataframe based on your item and date columns (in `ascending` order which is the default) and return the last row using `tail`:

```
df.sort_values(['item','date']).groupby(['item']).tail(1)

  item  price       date
0    A   11.2 2021-12-31
1    B   32.4 2021-12-31
2    C   75.5 2021-12-31
```

The `pd.to_datetime` part will ensure that your date is of datetime type. So essentially you need:

```
df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).sort_values(['item','date']).groupby(['item']).tail(1)
```